# Trying to create a view from 2 tables but contains no data

Tags: sql, oracle

The view has been created with the following statement. It all seems to work but there is no data there - do I need to specify the string?? Not sure what I'm doing here??

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW NEW_VIEW_VW
(
   URL,
   ORGANISATION,
   CATEGORY,
   SEARCH_1,
   SEARCH_2
)
AS
   SELECT DISTINCT,
   TABLE1.SERV_URL,
   TABLE2.ORGANISATION,
   TABLE1.SEARCH_1,
   TABLE1.SEARCH_2

FROM      TABLE1,
          TABLE2;

CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM NEW_VW;
DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM NEW_VIEW_VW;
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM NEW_VIEW_VW;
GRANT SELECT ON NEW_VIEW_VW;
```

Comment: Stupid question from me: both Table1 and Table2 contain data right?

Comment: Am I missing something or did you want a cartesian product?

Comment: Yes, both table 1 and 2 contain data so that for example URL will be populated from serv.url column in table 1, ORGANISATION will be populated from the organisation column in table 2 etc. The category field is not determined by a table and only exists in the view (a default value). Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if I actually need the DISTINCT there?

Comment: What is your select statement?

Comment: The code you've shown will not work - it has several syntax errors. Maybe you're still seeing a previous version of the view?

Comment: @AlexPoole: good question, but the 'force' in the statement will usually mean the object will get invalid when having an error instead of not updating the view. But of course you can never rule out the human factor.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - true, but depends how far the parser gets I think. The blank line makes me wonder if it's executing the `create` at all, if it's running in SQL*Plus. Either way there should be some kind of error, from the `create`, the last `grant` and/or the `select`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman -it doesn't even need the blank line; the `DISTINCT,` means it gets ORA-00936 and doesn't touch an existing view. Without the comma it would replace the view but be invalid, indeed.

Comment: @AlexPoole: you are right. When running in TOAD this statement is OK, but I have seen times Oracle didn't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is expecting 5 columns and select clause only has 4 cols

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW NEW_VIEW_VW
(
   URL,
   ORGANISATION,
   CATEGORY,
   SEARCH_1,
   SEARCH_2
)
AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
      TABLE1.SERV_URL,
      TABLE2.ORGANISATION,
      'xyz' category            ---- this col is missing
      TABLE1.SEARCH_1,
      TABLE1.SEARCH_2
 FROM TABLE1,
      TABLE2;
```

Also do you need a where clause to join the 2 tables?

Comment: The comma after `DISTINCT` will still get an ORA-00936; and you're missing one after `category`. It isn't clear if `DISTINCT` is needed at all. It does seem unlikely that a cartesian product would be desirable though...

Comment: My mistake--I removed the comma after distinct as that would cause an error.   I updated the code above.